# Read Bluetooth LE characteristic user description on android device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have successfully add the characteristic `user description (0x2901)` into all of my characteristics.

I used `nordic master control panel android app` to verify that my characteristics has characteristic user description such as: `SWITCH-1 (a meaning full name for me)` but I have problem getting this description from my own android application.

In my android application I’m able to find the services and characteristics but I don’t know how to read the characteristic user description value `(UUID 0x2901)`, I search the web many times with no luck.

Please give me suggestion to read characteristic user description on android device.